# When to put () on upper class and when not?

Tags: kotlin

[image]

This is Kotlin but in other languages, I have this question.

When we put sub class in super class or when we call members in class, I see sometimes people put `()` on that parent class and sometimes not.

- `Outer`.Nested().foo()
- `Outer()`.Nested().foo()

what makes some have `()` and some not?

Comment: Your question is understandable as-is, but please improve it by copying the _text_ of your code (not a screenshot of it). That will make it possible for search engines to pick up, and help future people with the same question. Additionally, please keep in mind that [StackOverflow is an English-language site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), so please translate the text between your two code blocks. Thanks!

Comment: first one is a "static class" and instances can be created alone, second one is "inner class" and you have to have instance of outer class to create instance of inner class - therforen creation via Outer()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html), these are the key sentences:

> A nested class marked as `inner` can access the members of its outer class. Inner classes carry a reference to an object of an outer class:

Without `inner`, the nested class is basically just a code organizational tool: the `Nested` class is its own, independent class. Other than the `Outer.Nested` notation (and things like [functional visibility](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html)), the instances of the two classes are essentially unrelated.

But with `inner`, each `Nested` instance can see its `Outer`'s instance members. To do that, it needs to know which instance of `Outer`. That means that each `inner Nested` instance needs to be created within the context of a specific `Outer` instance. That's what `Outer()` is doing. You could have also done:

```
val oObj = Outer()
val iObj = oObj.Inner() // "iObj" carries a reference to "oObj"
```